# Extra valves on AC lineset?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, mini-split, ductless

I'm installing a mini-split system in my shop, but realize I’ll probably need to move the outdoor unit in 6-12 months. Does it make sense to try to add a pair of valves to each line to allow them to be detached without losing refrigerant? Is that even possible?

Comment: Do you have an hvac License? There are DIY systems that have self sealing valves that you can legally set up and move. A standard line set would require a pump down of the lines. So this is not really something you could do in most of the world that requires licensing to open a system.

Comment: Right, I guess I’m asking if there’s a way to do this without having to let the refrigerant out. Do you have a link for these self-sealing line sets? All I’ve found is systems you can diy install (ie one time).

Comment: Rick the self sealing valves are in diy type systems. They cost as much more than a service call because they are that they are very expensive to make.  a section removable you would need 2 sets. The diy systems have a fixed line set length the extra is coiled up at the compressor. I don’t know of a source for them or if they are even field installable. At the + 400$ price tag of diy systems I only learned about them a year back as a training thing because DIY folks don’t have testers to verify leaks and leakage was the cause of failure. So I won’t be even trying them if I could find them.